# I want to make a button DISABLE in Matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-guide

I have an image, slider and a button. 
By moving the slider the image rotated, by pressing the button the image is saved.
There also is a text box that write the angle of rotation. 
**I want to make the button disable until the user move to slider**. 
(the slider can come back to the The initial situation)

this is the code

```
 function [angle] = rotationGUI()

    I = imread('frames/001.jpg');
    %# c
    hFig = figure('menu','none');
    hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);

    hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[290 28 20 15], 'String','0');
    uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', 'Value',0, 'Min',0,...
        'Max',360, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./360, ...
        'Position',[150 5 300 20], 'Callback',{@slider_callback,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig})


    uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','Save and Close',...
        'Position',[10 20 120 40],'Callback',{@ok_Callback,I,hTxt,hFig,'frames/001.jpg'});



    %# show image
    imshow(I, 'Parent',hAx)
    %# Callback function
    return;
    end
        function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig)
    global angle
    global Irot
    angle = round(get(hObj,'Value'));        %# get rotation angle in degrees

    Irot = imrotate(I,angle);
    imshow(Irot, 'Parent',hAx)  %# rotate image
    if (angle==0) 
        angle=360;
    end
    set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(angle))       %# update text
    end


function ok_Callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hTxt,hFig,path1)

    global Irot
    global angle
    set(hTxt, 'String','save')
    imwrite(Irot,path1);

    delete(hFig);
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give your button a handle every function can access, like this

```
    h.Button=uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton',...
```

then you give the handle to the other functions and can either deactivate it by setting the callback to {} or just not showing it, while you don't want it to be clicked. Looks like this:

```
    set(h.Button,'callback',{});
```

or

```
    set(h.Button,'Visible','off');
```

Of course you have to set the callback or visible option again to the right callback or 'on' when you want it to work again. I think you find out where to insert it in your code by yourself :)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the button a handle like this: 
`buttonhandle = uicontrol(...)`.

And when you declare the button you need to add a line to the components of the button which disables the button: `..., 'enable', 'off'`.

Then you need to pass it as an argument to the slider function callback, then in the slider function have a line `set(buttonhandle, 'enable', 'on')`.

And your button declaration has to be above the slider declaration else the slider callback function is taking in an invalid argument.

Answer (score 0):

**tnx for your help!!!!! 
you help me alot**

the final code is

```
function [angle] = rotationGUI()

I = imread('frames/001.jpg');
%# c
hFig = figure('menu','none');
hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);
global hButton;


hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[290 28 20 15], 'String','0');
uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', 'Value',0, 'Min',0,...
    'Max',360, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./360, ...
    'Position',[150 5 300 20], 'Callback',{@slider_callback,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig})

hButton=uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','Save and Close',...
    'Position',[10 20 120 40],'Callback',{@ok_Callback,I,hTxt,hFig,'frames/001.jpg'});
set(hButton,'Enable','off');



imshow(I, 'Parent',hAx)
    return;
end
    function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig)
global angle
global Irot
global hButton
set(hButton,'Enable','on');
angle = round(get(hObj,'Value'));        %# get rotation angle in degrees

Irot = imrotate(I,angle);
imshow(Irot, 'Parent',hAx)  %# rotate image
if (angle==0) 
    angle=360;
end
set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(angle))       %# update text
end

function ok_Callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hTxt,hFig,path1)

global Irot
global angle
set(hTxt, 'String','save')
imwrite(Irot,path1);

delete(hFig);
end
```